# ASP page to invoke PHP page in background

Tags: php, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP site that uses "crontab" to invoke a process every hour.

"1.php" (Linux) is run hourly (via crontab) and invokes
"2.php" (Windows) which invokes (via curl)
"3.asp" (Windows) which creates and invokes (via ASP's Server.Transfer)
"4.php" (Windows) which invokes a REST API.

Everything works great until the Server.Transfer to "4.php" -- it doesn't!

There are no "echo" (Linux) or "Response.Write" (Windows) statements.
Processing involves database and file system access.

I know that I had to use "curl" (or "wget") to invoke a page from a "cron" job
because it isn't running within a browser.

I thought I could use Server.Transfer (not Response.Redirect) within ASP.
Apparently, Server.Transfer can only be used to transfer to another ASP page.

Might someone suggest a solution?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: why can't you use response.redirect?

Comment: One other thought.  Does 3.asp contain any client side html.  If it does you could hit 4.php with an iframe with zero height and width

Comment: Response.Redirect is used in browser (not background) sessions. This is a background task that does not render any HTML.

Comment: Response.Redirect has nothing to do with browser in my opinion it just sends a http Status code 301 (Moved Permanently). you are using http to call the php and asp pages right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a server http request

```
Dim objXML
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
objXML.Open "GET", "http://fullurlto/4.php", false 
objXML.Send
Response.Write objXML.responseText
Set objXML = nothing
```

Comment: I got the following error: msxml6.dll error '80072ee6' System error: -2147012890. This is a background task, why Response.Write?  I'm using shared hosting.

Comment: It seems to work (in a standalone test) when I specified an absolute URL; I had tried a relative URL which failed. I changed it to Server.CreateObject(). I'll try a real test and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't need the output of the php page then you don't need the response.write line.  That error message suggests that the server doesn't like http requests made to itself.  What does 4.php look like.  You might be able to invoke your API directly with asp

Comment: I did give me this error: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6' Object doesn't support this property or method: 'responseText' but I don't need it (do I?).

Comment: No, but it certainly should support response text.  You certainly do need to use an absolute url, You're requesting it as if it were an external page

Comment: Twilio doesn't support ASP.

Comment: You sometimes have to dig a bit for classic asp examples. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2010/04/using-twilio-with-classic-asp-and-vbscript.html.  I recommend using Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") though rather than Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") - it uses a later version of the component

Comment: Your solution works great!  Thank you. Also, Twilio doesn't support ASP.

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks for the link to the blog post! I'll look into it.